# Get variable value in single quote in dynamic SQL query

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

Please help me to get date output in single quote.

```
validity='`date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-%d) +45 days" +%Y-%m-%d`'

"select 'ALTER USER ' || usename || ' valid until '"$validity"';' from pwdhistory where date(changed_on) = current_date;"
```

We need output of above query in below format.

```
ALTER USER username valid until '2021-8-09';  (We want date should be in single quote)
```

Thanks.

Comment: 1. this can't work with single-quotes, use double-quotes around the command substitution. 2. don't use backticks for command subst, use `$(date -d .....)` instead. 3. don't try to do this in shell, or you're in for a world of pain with quoting and white space issues.  Use a language with decent library support for whatever SQL database you're using - e.g. [DBI](https://dbi.perl.org/) for perl, and maybe something like [SQL Alchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for python (or sqlalchemy may be overkill, maybe look for something a bit simpler than an object-relational mapper).

Comment: BTW, one of the many reasons for using another language (**any** other language, shell is probably the worst possible choice for sql scripting) is that the db libraries for them support placeholders in sql statetements that automatically handle quoting where required.